# How to keep json-server alive permanently?

Tags: json-server

How to keep json-server alive permanently?
As of now, when '`npx json-server --w db.json`' this command is ran then json server starts but if my laptop gets off then the server also stops running.
Any solution for it?

**Note: I tried my-json-server.typicode.com but my .json file is too big so its not working**

Comment: "when your laptop gets off"? So you are wondering that your program stops when you turn your computer off? Or are you asking how to automatically restart your program when you turn on your computer?

Comment: the JSON-SERVER should not stop even if I turn my computer off.

Answer (score 0):

What you're (were) looking for is to "deploy" your app (ie. to make put it on a server somewhere on the internet).

There's many options to deploy a node app but, for json-server, you may find this the easiest:

https://dev.to/juliang/persistent-rest-api-with-json-server-and-glitch-32kc